# How can I set Imageview and Textview on same line in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I want to set Imageview and Textview on same line in LinearLayout but the Imageview is always higher than the Textview.

Here is my code:

```
String b[] = cacBuocThucHien.split("#");
for (int j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(30,30);
    lp.setMargins(50, 0, 0, 0);
    ImageView img = new ImageView(RecipesDetailActivity.this);
    TextView tv = new TextView(RecipesDetailActivity.this);
    img.setLayoutParams(lp2);
    img.setImageResource(R.mipmap.testic);
    tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
    tv.setText(b[j] + "\n");
    layoutHuongDan.addView(img);
    layoutHuongDan.addView(tv);
}
```

Comment: You should add gravity to the views - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775705/android-set-the-gravity-for-a-textview-programmatically

Comment: You might be looking for [How to display image in Android's TextView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561981/how-to-display-image-in-androids-textview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This You can use to put image in one line.. and it will work in all kind of layouts. Hope this will help you

```
  <LinerLayout>     
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   ....... // Put how many TextViews you want

 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
 </LinerLayout>
```

You can set visibility gone initially if you wanna show these textviews only after setting text.
Now in your activity make an array of ids of textviews like this...

```
public static int[] textRows = {R.id.text1, R.id.text2, ........ R.id.textn};
```

then use for loop for initializing them and setting text and images like this

```
   TextView[] allTexts = new TextView[n];
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        allTexts[i] = (TextView) findViewById(textRows[i]);
        allTexts[i].setText("your text");
        allTexts[i].setCompoundDrawables(left_image, null, null, null); 
    }
```

It will work. Try it out

Comment: Thank for your help but I tried your method but with this way the imageview disappear and I can't add multi imageview and textview and either.

Comment: I want to add one text with one image in front of it for per line, so I have to create texts and images with "for" loop and use linear layout.

Comment: see my edits, and check it.. It should work as per requirement.

Comment: I learn a new thing from you,thank you for your help. But this is not actually what I want, I just want a small icon in front of the first letter of the textview. How can I do that?

Comment: Here. I want something like this
http://s16.postimg.org/m423udgmd/Untitled.png
But follow your instruction, it will be like this
http://s11.postimg.org/g7al92eub/Untitled.jpg

Comment: okay... Do one thing, create a custom listview, item of listview will hold an image and text as per ur snap, then populate listview using adapter.

Comment: Ok, so there is no way we can do this with linear layout, right? My teammates don't want to use listview but I will ask them again to see if they change their mind. Thank you for your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

set textview drawable left no need of extra imageview

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/img"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to show an icon beside that `TextView`, in my opinion you should consider using [drawable icon feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4502650/1841194) of `TextView`

```
tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.icon, 0, 0, 0);
```

But if you would insist to using two views beside each other, using [layout gravity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4783896/1841194) would be useful in such circumstances.

```
lp.gravity= Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
```

Comment: When I try 1st method, the layout will be blank. And when I try 2nd method, the icon will be on top of the textview.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display only `TextView` and `ImageView`.. go for setting `CompounDrawable` in `TextView` itself..

But, for having two views side-by-side in `LinearLayout` programmatically try setting the `orientation=horizontal`, check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6261471/3485152).